# How do I convert a Linux C USB read to Android?

Tags: android, usb

I have Tire Pressure Management System (TPMS) adapter that plugs into USB (http://store.mp3car.com/USB_TPMS_Version_2_20_4_Sensor_Kit_p/com-090.htm). I have it working with the original Windows software, as well as Linux C code to read the tire pressures and temperature. I'm now trying to use this adapter on Android and am having some difficulty. I can detect the device fine, but my reads are all returning -1 bytes read, whatever I try. Here's the C code I'm trying to convert:

```
int TpmsPlugin::readUsbSensor(int sid, unsigned char *buf)
{
  int r, transferred;

  buf[0] = 0x20 + sid;
  r = libusb_interrupt_transfer(mDeviceHandle, ENDPOINT_OUT, buf, 1, &transferred, INTR_TIMEOUT);
  if (r < 0) {
    DebugOut() << "TPMS: USB write interrupt failed, code " << r << endl;
  }

  r = libusb_interrupt_transfer(mDeviceHandle, ENDPOINT_IN, buf, 4, &transferred, INTR_TIMEOUT);
  if (r < 0) {
    DebugOut() << "TPMS: USB read interrupt failed, code " << r << endl;
  }

  return r;
```

The value of sid is 1, 2, 3 or 4 depending on the wheel. The values are then extracted with:

```
    lfPressure = ((float)buf[0]-40) * PRESSURE_SCALE * KPA_MULTIPLIER;
    lfTemperature = (float)buf[1]-40;
```

You can see full implementation of this driver here as well: https://github.com/otcshare/automotive-message-broker/blob/master/plugins/tpms/tpmsplugin.cpp

My Android version is able to find the USB device, get permission to use it, connect to it, get the UsbEndpoints (it lists two), but whether bulkTransfer() or controlTransfer() I try, I've failed. In particular, I've tried a lot of different controlTransfer values based on all the docs I could find. Here is some code that I've tried:

```
UsbInterface intf = TpmsSectionFragment.device.getInterface(0);
UsbEndpoint endpoint_in = null, endpoint_out = null;
for (int i = 0; i < intf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
    UsbEndpoint ep = intf.getEndpoint(i);
    if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
        endpoint_in = ep;
    else if (ep.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT)
        endpoint_out = ep;
}

UsbDeviceConnection connection = gUsbManager.openDevice(TpmsSectionFragment.device); 
connection.claimInterface(intf, false);
int timeout = 1000;
int length = 4;

while (true) {
    for (int sensorId = 1; sensorId <= 4 && mReadThreadActive; sensorId++) {

        byte[] tpmsRaw = new byte[length];
        tpmsRaw[0] = (byte) (0x20 + sensorId);
        int out_len = connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint_out, tpmsRaw, 1, timeout);
        int in_len = connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint_in, tpmsRaw, 4, timeout);
        //int out_len = connection.controlTransfer(0x42, 0x0, 0x100, 0, tpmsRaw, tpmsRaw.length, timeout);
        //int in_len = connection.controlTransfer(0x41, 0x0, 0x100, 0, tpmsRaw, tpmsRaw.length, timeout);
```

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong are greatly appreciated. I'm happy to try a few different things to debug further if you have any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Your libusb code implies you need to use an **interrupt transfer** rather than the synchronous bulk or control transfer methods you tried.  Please read the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbRequest.html particularly "Requests on bulk endpoints can be sent synchronously via bulkTransfer(UsbEndpoint, byte[], int, int) or asynchronously via queue(ByteBuffer, int) and requestWait(). **Requests on interrupt endpoints are only send and received asynchronously**."  I'm seeing suggestions the missile launcher code might be a relevant example.

Comment: sounds like a cool project.

Comment: Chris, thank you so much for the response. With a few tweaks I just got it to work. I'll post a note with code below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution based on the help from Chris. I converted the calls to queue / requestWait:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
buf.put(0, (byte) (0x20 + sensorId));

UsbRequest send = new UsbRequest();
send.initialize(connection, endpoint_out);
Boolean sent = send.queue(buf, 1);
UsbRequest r1 = connection.requestWait();

send.initialize(connection, endpoint_in);
send.queue(buf, 4);
UsbRequest r2 = connection.requestWait();
```

The other thing I needed to tweak was this call and set the second parameter to true:

```
connection.claimInterface(intf, true);
```

That's it. Done. Thanks for the help!